# Div width inheriting strangely with position fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an audio player, with playbutton, progress bar, and stop button. I want it to be fixed to the bottom of the page.

So to do this I have the following CSS:

```
.player-container {
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #505050; 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Now, the weird thing, is what happens to the width. The player container is contained in a Bootstrap container. It usually starts in the correct place, but depending on the width of the browser, it seems to bunch up all small - or it seems to be the normal length, plus the size of the padding, which is really odd.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="player-container" ng-show="showPlayer" ng-controller="PlayerController">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play music-control"></span>
      <div class="seekBase" seek-track></div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop music-control" stop-music ng-click="stopClicked()"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a plnkr to display what is happening, with different color backgrounds to make it all very clear:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MU4aK6Wf4UUmQh4egqU7

Is the 'position: fixed' causing all this to go crazy? Ideas on a postcard....

Comment: Which is the `width` of the parent `.container`?

Comment: The width of the container is determined by the bootstrap css i think.

Comment: If you check the CSS value of your width to 100% the problem is solved

Comment: width of 100% just makes it go the whole way across the screen - it doesn't stop where the container does. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/M3tIGPSgJ4CwE0CE0GjX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inherit` keyword sets the specified and computed values to the computed value of the same property on the parent element.

The problem is that bootstrap may set some `width` to the parent `.container` depending on the width of the browser (by using  `min-width` `@media` queries).

When the browser is narrow, the parent `.container` has no cascaded value for `width`. Therefore, since`width` is not an inherited property, the specified value is `auto`. For `width`, `auto` computes to `auto`. Then, `inherit` makes `.player-container` have an `auto` `width` too.So  `width: inherit` does not affect `.player-container` in this case.

If you want this behavior when the browser is not narrow, remove `width: inherit` and let it be `auto`.

However, when the browser is wider, `.container` may have widths like `750px`, `970px` or `1170px`. In this case, `.player-container` will inherit that same width.

If you want this behavior when the browser is narrow, use `width: 100%`.

Comment: Ok - so I should use media queries for the particular sizes and set the width accordingly within those. This doesn't help with the strange padding problem. The red 'test' div without any width set gets given the width of the parent element minus the padding. However, when i do another div and give it a green background and use width:inherit, it gets given the size of the full element, including the padding. Even when I set the padding to inherit it still gets the background colour! See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/261SeCOsNgd0DiPoilUq

Comment: @TomO'Brien If container has `width: 970px; padding: 15px`, then an in-flow block child with `width: auto` will cover available space, that is, `940px`. But if you use `width: 100%` or `width: inherit`, the child will have `width: 970px`, you it will overflow the container.

Comment: Right - but this only seems to happen when I use position fixed as this plnkr shows: http://plnkr.co/edit/e6RAutbgrMwOJgEudN8n . Is there any way to get around this behaviour when i fix the div to the bottom? I suppose that is the crux of the question?

Comment: @TomO'Brien Don't use `width: inherit`. Only use `inherit` when you want to inherit some value from parent. But you don't want to inherit `width`, you want it to be always some value (I don't know which). Just set `width` to that value.

Comment: Ok - so on the media queries for the different sizes that the container sets the width, I just match the width? That should work?

Comment: OK, now I understand the issue. You want it to be as wide as the container, but the problem is that, since its fixedly positioned, the containing block is the viewport. Yes, an option would be setting the width in media queries. The proper solution would be `position: sticky; bottom: 0`, but not all browsers support it yet.